# Robots.txt Error on Google Search Console

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-search-console

While I am submitting my website robots.txt to Google Search Console it's showing as an error like the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Which domain do you have?

Comment: Y'all need http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and jebus.  But mostly http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the robots.txt file to the root. Check it yourself by going to yourdomain.com/robots.txt.
If it works, then it ... works! It can take a while before Google updates the status in Search Console. Sometimes you need to lift your eyes from Search Console ;-)

Answer (score -1):

It's an not an error. its saying upload the robot.txt file in the root directry of your website. And then ask google to update the robot.txt file.